# Flutter:Firebase authentication and mapview

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've been working on app which requires map support and user authentication login. I created an app with map view its working fine when I tried to add fire base user authentication. Map view is not working

Code Sample :

Main Page:

```
 class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MapPageState createState() => new _MapPageState();
    }

    class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
      MapView view =new MapView();
      CameraPosition cameraPosition;
      var staticMapProvider =new StaticMapProvider(apiKey);
      Uri staticMapUri;

      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        cameraPosition =new CameraPosition(new Location(13.007515, 80.208595), 15.0);
        staticMapUri =staticMapProvider.getStaticUri(new Location(13.007515, 80.208595),12,height: 200,width: 200,
        mapType: StaticMapViewType.roadmap);
      }

      showMap()
      {
        view.show(new MapOptions(
          title: "Location Tracking" ,
          showUserLocation: true,
          initialCameraPosition:  new CameraPosition(new Location(13.007515, 80.208595), 150.0),
          mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
        )
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
            child: new InkWell(
             child : new Image.network(staticMapUri.toString()),
              onTap:
                showMap
            )
            ),
          );
      }
    }
```

android/build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
    }
```

android/app/build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:

  map_view:  
  firebase_auth: '^0.5.5'
  cloud_firestore:
```

Issue that I get:

```
**I/art     (11855): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class ava.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition>

F/flutter (11855): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(60)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 

F/libc    (11855): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11855 (ompany.retroapp)
Lost connection to device.**
```

and when I removed fire base authentication and its dependencies. Map view is working fine.
How can I integrate firebase authentication and map view?

Comment: What do you add in your project to cause that issue to appear? I know it's Firebase authentication but what files do you modified or what lines of code do you add? (post them in your question)

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions.

Comment: ok sure..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its occurs when firebase and mapview use different version of google play services.

It can be solved by adding this line in app/build.gradle file.

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Add this line in build.gradle file

```
  subprojects {
    // project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where to add this com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
Add this line in app/ build.gradle

Comment: Add that line in app/build.gradle file